Change alignment of ttk.Menubutton label to Left (or Right)
When I create ttk.Menubutton its label is always centered.

I need the label 0x0 be justified to left. Since it is themed widget its constructor doesn't let change anchor or justify options. Tried that, get an exception.
I tried change style like this:
ttk.Style().configure('TMenubutton', justify='left')
ttk.Style().configure('TMenubutton.label', justify='left')
but it had zero effect.
